# jquery tabs - load url in current tab?

Tags: jquery, load, tabs

I'm trying to figure out how to load the url each tab links to inside the tab area onclick, and have been trying to following the docs at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...open_links_in_the_current_tab_instead_of_leaving_the_page, but am clearly not getting it....

This is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabNav">
    <li><a href="/1.html#tabone">Tab One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2.html#tabtwo">Tab Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3.html#tabthree">Tab Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> 

<div id="tabone"> 
     <!-- Trying to load content from 1.html in this div on click --> 
</div>

<div id="tabtwo"> 
     <!-- Trying to load content from 2.html in this div on click --> 
</div>

<div id="tabthree"> 
     <!-- Trying to load content from 3.html in this div on click --> 
</div>
```

And this is the jquery I'm trying to use:

```
$(".tabs").tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
            $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
                    $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                    return false;
                });
    }
    });
```

I know I've got some part of this wrong.... I've gone through several iterations (too many to post), and all I get is a blank div...  I don't know...  Feeling a bit confused here...  Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you reference is intended for loading links referenced **on the tab** in the current tab, not loading the tab itself from a link.  You shouldn't need to use the load method to get links as tabs to work.

All you really should need is this (you can omit the `tab` container `DIVS`).  I'm assuming that the other tabs are relative and represent the full tab contents so I've removed the leading `/` and the hash.

```
<div class="tabs"> 
  <ul class="tabNav"> 
    <li><a href="1.html" title="Tab One">Tab One</a></li> 
    <li><a href="2.html" title="Tab Two">Tab Two</a></li> 
    <li><a href="3.html" title="Tab Three">Tab Three</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  // note wrap in 'ready" function to make sure DOM is loaded
        $('.tabs).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

And please make sure you add following JS code also after loading tabs.

```
$('#tabs ul li.ui-tabs-selected a').click(function(){
                location.href = $(this).attr('href');
                return false;
        }).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Cheers!!!